# Are HP Nonstop servers becoming less common in the Enterprise?

Tags: ibm

I'm a system admin for a HP Nonstop server.  Recently, the vendors (ACI) of the main application we use (Base24) announced a partnership with IBM to move future releases of the application to the z/OS platform.  I'm curious as to whether other HP Nonstop users see similar things happening in their line of work.  I can't find any other posts about these servers here so maybe I've already answered my own question!

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I even *know* anyone who uses Nonstop.

Comment: Same here, never seen one in a shop before, and don't think I know anyone who has.

Comment: @Cian @mrdenny Well there are very few in Ireland, 3 to be precise.  Mainly used in financial and manufacturing companies.  Amazon have hundreds apparently, Barclays, Dell etc

Comment: We used several at my last shop.  They migrated off the original Tandems onto the HP Nonstop hosts for support.  The native applications had been running for over a decade on that platform and porting onto another system was just not cost-effective.

Comment: Thanks @KevinRae, surprising to hear those old machines were still in use.  I've never seen one.  Doesn't look to be too many people on here with exposure to Nonstop either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, we got rid of every one of ours.

Comment: What was it used for?  Do you know what version it was, as in what generation?  K-Series, S-Series, Integrity, Blade?

Thanks

Comment: Ours were Integrity that we used for card payment approval proxies, went over to Oracle clusters on x86 blades.